# javascript Create and find value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, filter

I have a JavaScript object with the following properties

```
{
  name:"Request",
  data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
},
{
  name:"Waiting",
  data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
}
```

I have a list that has status (name) and month ( data:[]) 
First I want to validate whether the object with the name eg "Request" exists.

If it does not exist, create a new object.
 `{ name:'Request', data:[]}`.

If the name already exists, it will check if the month exists in the object array "data". If there is no month in the array you must enter it.
`{name:'Request', data:[1]}`

Comment: Take a look at the tips for formatting your code.  You'll get better responses if people can easily read what you've written.

Comment: ... and do not spam irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do if everything is successful, but the code below should satisfy the requirements you have provided.

```js
var objs = [{
  name:"Request",
  data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
},
{
  name:"Waiting",
  data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
}];

var month = 25;

var request = null;
// Validate whether the object with the name eg "Request" exists.
var requestExists = objs.some(function (elem) {
  if (elem.name === "Request") {
    request = elem;
    return true;
  }
});
//If it does not exist, create a new object.  { name:'Request', data:[]}.
if(!requestExists) {
  objs.push({name: "Request", data: []});
}
else {
// If the name does exist, check if the month exists in the "data" array. 
// If there is no month in the array you must enter it. {name:'Request', data:[1]}
  if (request.data.indexOf(month) === -1) {
    request.data.push(month);
  }
}

console.log(request);
console.log(objs);
```

Comment: But the objs, initially does not exist, it is blank. as it is initialized just put var obj = new array (); ?

Comment: @JoséFidalgo That's fine, this code will handle that. You will get an array that looks like the following: `[{ name: "Request", data: [] }]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [{
  name:"Waiting",
  data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
}]

var request = list.filter(status => status.name == "Request");

if (request.length === 0) list.push({name : "Request", data : [1]});
else if (request[0].data.length === 0) request[0].data.push(1);

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since with the OP's example a data structure has to be checked and repaired whilst following some rules, a more generic approach should look for kind of a specific sanitizer function that can be both operated by itself (providing the key manually) but also run as a reduce method, if it comes to counterchecking the data structure against more than one data item key (like "Request" as it got provided with the OP's original example).

A solution then most probably will be close to the next provided one.

The [`Array` API Documentation of the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) does provide polyfills for [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill) and [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill)

```js
function sanitizeDataList(list, key) {
  var
    indexOfDataItem = list.findIndex(function (dataItem) {
      return (dataItem.name === key);
    }),
    dataItem = list[indexOfDataItem];

  if (!dataItem) {
    list.push(dataItem = {
      name: key
    });
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(dataItem.data) || (dataItem.data.length <= 0)) {
    dataItem.data = [1];
  }
  return list;
}


var
  dataList = [{
    name: "Request_A",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  }, {
    name: "Waiting_A",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  }/*, {
    name: "Request_B",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  }*/, {
    name: "Waiting_B",
    data: []
  }, {
    name: "Request_C"
  }, {
    name: "Waiting_C",
    data: [1]
  }],

  dataItemKeyList = ["Request_A", "Waiting_A", "Request_B", "Waiting_B", "Request_C", "Waiting_C"];


dataList = dataItemKeyList.reduce(sanitizeDataList, dataList);


console.log(dataList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @JoséFidalgo ... how come that you first award this as the accepted answer and then withdraw it seconds later? Has it been awarded accidentally or was it just not good enough in comparison with the now/currently accepted one?

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution is to use indexOf. You would need for it to be in a variable.

```js
var myarray = [{
       name:"Request",
       data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
       },
       {name:"Waiting",
       data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
       
       }];
var myreturn = false;       
for(i = 0; myarray.length > i; i++){
  var data = myarray[i];
  if(data.name == "Request"){
    myreturn = true;
    }
    if (myreturn === true){
     alert('sweet now do some code');
     break;
    }
}
```

My initial thought was incorrect, but using a For loop will work.

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid, but even if it was, indexOf does not look inside objects.

Comment: How do I initialize the array?

Comment: re-look, I was incorrect, using a for loop is the correct solution

Comment: there is no initialization, you can use a click or even just a simple windows.load to run this.